# Is $L$ is a splitting field ? Yes/No

Tags: field-theory

Given  $$L={\bf Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\dots)$$

Here ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\dots)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$
because  any  irreducible polynomial $ f(x)$ over the rationals with a zero in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\dots)$ splits into linear factors over $K$.

we know that a field extension $L/K$ is a splitting field  if $f(x)$ split in $L$

so by the definition $f(x)$  split inside  ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\dots)$  this implies ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\dots)$ is a splitting field

Comment: Splitting field is in reference to some polynomial and then it is always a finite extension. More precisely if $f(x) $ is polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in field $F$ then the splitting field $L$ of $f(x) $ over $F$ has degree at most $n! $.

Answer (score 1):

According to  Paramanand singh comment we have

Here  $L$ is infinite and roots of $f(x)$ is finite .So $ L$ can never obtained from adjoining the roots of $f(x)$

This implies that $L$  is not a splitting field